# Arithmetic vs Geometric Mean

Tags: statistics

I have a score between 0 and 1 associated with each unique word in my text.

I then establish a Sentence Score for each sentence in my text. I'm not sure if I should be using an Arithmetic Mean or a Geometric Mean to calculate the Sentence Score, so I use both thereby generating two separate scores.

So of the sentence "get out", with get = 0.9 and out = 0.8 I will get an Arithmetic Mean of 0.85.

I then do an Arithmetic Mean on all the sentence scores for a given sentence length, with the results as follows:

```
Sentence Length:    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

Sentence Score via Geometric Mean:  0.4764016095    0.5671917075    0.5685724918    0.5565666797    0.5354215885    0.5300766966    0.5176706042    0.4981456651    0.4866116085    0.4736282138

Sentence Score via Arithmetic Mean: 0.4778932149    0.6485239986    0.7017139098    0.7159427493    0.7153209927    0.7202494746    0.7184521287    0.7111340547    0.7078966864    0.7029980487
```

Why are the results so different? How can I interpret the results? Which mean should I be using in your opinion in order to associate a score with the sentence?

Comment: The results are different because you use different methods. Whether arithmetic or geometric (or any other) mean is more appropriate to your application depends .. on your application.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen My application is to generate a score for the sentence. What I'm interested in is what factors would cause me to get a higher Sentence Score for a sentence when using the AM over the GM and vice versa. Form this I can decide myself as to which Mean to use.

Comment: What is a "Sentence Score"?

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla The "Sentence Score" measures the usefulness of a sentence with respect to a learner. Learners want to hear as many common words as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Geometric Mean is more biased towards lower numbers. So if I have a sentence of length 5, and 4 of the words in this sentence have really high scores but one has a really low score, then the Sentence Score will be lowish.

GM([1,1,1,1,0.01]) = 0.39811

not high as with the AM:

AM([1,1,1,1,0.01]) = 0.802

All the word scores need to be high with the GM to get a high score.

So if a low scored sentence is defined as a sentence having even one low scored word, then the GM is better than the AM.

However, another extreme would be to score the sentence with the minimum word value:

GM([1,1,1,1,0.01]) = 0.01